# Url Forwarding with masking showing Uncaught DOMException Error

Tags: html, web, url, hosting, godaddy-api

I have hosted a project on zappar. it is working fine. so i bought an domain in godaddy and forwarded its url. that also worked fine. Now when i try url forwarding with masking its showing following error. is there any way to fix this. anymore details needed i will provide. and i believe its not chrome cookies.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from
> 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
> at https://libs.zappar.com/zappar-cv/2.1.4/zappar-cv.js:1:306495
> at Ot (https://libs.zappar.com/zappar-cv/2.1.4/zappar-cv.js:1:306717)
> at https://libs.zappar.com/zappar-cv/2.1.4/zappar-cv.js:1:324893
> at Module.Vt (https://libs.zappar.com/zappar-cv/2.1.4/zappar-cv.js:1:324899)
> at https://g72q7.zappar.io/5898047692134420xxxx/1.1.22/:180:29

Below is my modified Url

> https://g72q7.zappar.io/5898047692134420xxxx/1.1.22/